# (P.H.P.MyAdmin 4.5.3.1+10.0.17-MariaDB) Why are click options executed with an incomplete WHERE clause on My tables?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, where-clause, mariadb

Table rows I inserted in database I created are unresponsive to clicks to change their values or delete rows:
[image]
[image]
    SELECT * FROM `Database`.`Table` WHERE ;
    DELETE FROM `TABLE` WHERE  LIMIT 1;

Of course I have an error in My SQL syntax; There's no need to check the manual that corresponds to my MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1, since I know reference (id=someNumber) is needed, But I thougt it should be added automatically. Should I configure something else in adittion to what I've already configured? All my Tables have their primary and unique keys.

Issue only happens with my tables in my database. System databases bring their rows for editing or even deleting them when I click their edit and delete links. Writing commands in consoles is no problem (textbox is marking invalid syntax for valid syntax, but commands still run).

Since tools provided with currently X.A.M.P.P. most recent version (5.6.14) are outdated (P.H.P. 5.6.14) and messy with some tools included (P.H.P.MyAdmin 4.4.14, MariaDB 10.0.17). I updated them (5.6.15, 4.5.2, 10.1.19) by just downloading, replacing and rewriting their .ini's with the options usually mandatory and obviously demanding.

Tried new database with a single table of the ones I have: Here is the export:

CREATE TABLE Categoria(
id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
orden bigint(20) NOT NULL,
activa tinyint(4) DEFAULT 1,
nombre varchar(256) NOT NULL,
detalle varchar(512) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY nombre (nombre),
UNIQUE KEY orden (orden)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO Categoria (id,orden,activa,nombre,detalle) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'COBRE', 'Rradiadores, estañados y otros.'),
(2, 2, 1, 'BRONCE', 'rebaba, radiadores etc.. Se incluye al antimonio'),
(3, 3, 1, 'ALUMINIO', 'Rebaba, rines, perfiles, cables, botes, radiadores, litografías, aleaciones, etc.');

Problem persists. Maybe adding two unique keys confuses phpmyadmin.

I'm using Adminer in the meanwhile. It doesn't come with autocomplete in command, but everything else is just better.

Fresh Reinstall and similar does not help...That includes trying online demo, seing no problem and state indirectly tha I'm crazy.

So, if you know I missed something, please let me know...

Comment: Show us an export of your table's structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what details of the database are going to accomplish. Clearly the code that's building the query is the problem here.

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors in your example (on my machine) and ran it on demo.phpmyadmin.net with phpMyAdmin 4.5.1, choosing MariaDB (version  10.0.21). All is fine for me, browsing your table and clicking on Edit or Delete links for any of the rows.

Comment: fixed sintax, confirmed no problem on page too. Problem persists in my machine.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with database tables in MariaDB version 10.0.17.
There are some new and stable versions available.
Download MariaDB version 10.0.21 which is a stable version and the errors have been fixed.
As Marc said,the demo package of xampp uses MariaDB version 10.0.21 and therefore it shows no errors.
Please download the lates version from here:
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.0.21/

Please accept the answer if you are satisfied to remove this from the unanswered section.

Comment: Updated to 10.1.9. Problem persists.

Comment: Download MariaDB version 10.0.21.
This is a stable version.
I would suggest you to download and reinstall  xampp  which comes with MariaDB v10.0.21 and the latest phpmyadmin.

https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.0.21/

Comment: If the problem still persists,create a backup of your files.Uninstall xampp.
And install xampp version 5.6.14.
This is an older and better version.
This one actually worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

`WHERE` *must* have an expression after it.  It is up to you, not phpmyadmin, to provide something.  Or remove "WHERE".

`DELETE ... LIMIT 1` should have an `ORDER BY`, else which "1" will it delete??

Comment: Added images. Of course "id=aNumber" is missing, but that should be added in the links made to be clicked, or else there no reason for using phpmyadmin. Tried Adminer and is really better except that it does not com with autocomplete.

Comment: It can't guess that you want `WHERE id...`, not `WHERE foobar...`, etc.  Try a different version of phpmyadmin.